# TABLE NOT FOUND after restarting H2 database service

Tags: java, h2

We are facing a serious problem with H2 database, version 1.4.199 - server mode. The application data layer creates a table programmatically if not exists, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (...); 
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_mytable ON mytable(mycol);
```

and works fine for days, writing data into the above table. After restarting the service, at first connection attempt, the engine throws the error

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "mytable" not found; SQL statement:
> CREATE INDEX "PUBLIC"."IDX_MYTABLE" ON "PUBLIC"."MYTABLE"("MYCOL")

If we try recovering the database, the sql script does not contain the "mytable" anymore, so the data are definitevely lost! We have hundreds of installations of the software, but the error happens occasionally on some of them (10%).

Answer (score -1):

Ping us H2 properties which you used.
"spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" should be "update".

Comment: we don't use jpa, just jdbc connection server mode